# Ionic ngModel directive not updating $scope.property value in controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I have the following ionic template defined:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <label class="item item-input">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="name">
    </label>
    <button class="ion-plus-circled button button-block button-positive" ng-click="add()" side="right">
      Add Name
    </button>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And my controller looks like the following:

```
//home controller
.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','$log',
   function($scope,$log){
      $scope.name = null;
      $scope.add = function(){  
         var name = $scope.name;
         if(name != null && name != undefined){
            $log.debug('participant added to list:' + name);
         }else{
            //notify the user that they must enter a valid name
            $log.debug('user entered invalid name');
         }
    };
}])
```

When `add()` is invoked on `$scope`, the `$scope.name` value is null.

Thus, the code and markup above would result in the following to be logged.

`user entered invalid name`

Why does it not pickup the value from the textbox?

Comment: mention all() method of Participants service in post

Comment: works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/bpKfghCBgxNx4jTUl3C1?p=preview

Comment: @MukundKumar I removed references to `Participants` because it is not relevant to this post. Thanks.

Comment: @TheJediCowboy are you using Bootstrap (angular-ui version) too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

**Html:**

```
<button class="ion-plus-circled button button-block button-positive" ng-click="add(name)" side="right">
    Add Name
</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
 $scope.add = function(name){  
         if(name != null && name != undefined){
            $log.debug('participant added to list:' + name);
         }else{
            //notify the user that they must enter a valid name
            $log.debug('user entered invalid name');
         }
    };
```

**OR:**

**html:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="obj.name">
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.add = function(){  
         var name = $scope.obj.name;
         if(name != null && name != undefined){
            $log.debug('participant added to list:' + name);
         }else{
            //notify the user that they must enter a valid name
            $log.debug('user entered invalid name');
         }
    };
```